# Error while passing a where clause as a stored procedure parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created following stored procedure in SQL Server,

```
create procedure sp_test
    @columns nvarchar(max),
    @tablename nvarchar(max),
    @whereClause nvarchar(max)
as
   DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
   SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @columns + ' FROM ' + @tablename + @whereClause;

   EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

I am trying to call it like this

```
exec sp_test 'title,name','person','where name = ''john'''
```

And I'm getting an error like this,

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: thanks @ marc_s ill change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra single quote, why not use double quote, like:

```
exec sp_test 'title,name','person'," where name = 'john'"
```

Add an extra space also here:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @columns + ' FROM ' + @tablename+ ' ' + @whereClause;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** It's because

```
SELECT title,name FROM personwhere name = 'john'
```

is not a valid SQL.

The reason should be obvious now and is left as an exercise to the reader...